# Normal Alert Dialog in Android

Tags: android, google-play

The alert dialog appears as a custom alert dialog like the white one. How to make the alert dialog appear normal? Black and blue.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
```

[image]

[image]

`AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Hello")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setMessage("Hi")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", null)
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .setNeutralButton("Maybe", null);`

Can the Alert Dialog be changed without changing the entire theme?

Comment: In Different Different `Android OS Devices` you got different result but  if you want to fixed this then apply `Holo.Light Theme` to your `activity`. Yo got same result in any `Android OS Devices`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this**

```
ContextThemeWrapper themedContext;

if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ) {
    themedContext = new ContextThemeWrapper( this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_NoActionBar);
}
else {
    themedContext = new ContextThemeWrapper( this, android.R.style.Theme_Light_NoTitleBar );
}


AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(themedContext)

   // your dialog code.....
```

Comment: What about devices on Honeycomb? How can it be made so only devices using version 11 or above use this Holo theme?

Answer (score 2):

You can customize your alert dialog.

This is something you can do :

**Declare this code in your style.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AboutDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
<item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverseDisableOnly</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Now just create an instance of **ContextThemeWrapper** that uses your style, and pass that to the Builder instead of the activity context.

So, instead of something like this:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
```

…we now have something like this:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.AboutDialog))
```

There’s one more trick to getting this to work properly, and that’s to make sure you also use the same ContextThemeWrapper if you inflate a custom layout for the AlertDialog.

**In our case, I needed to change this:**

```
View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.about_dialog, null);
```

…to this:

```
View view = View.inflate(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.AboutDialog), R.layout.about_dialog, null);
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: How to make only devices using version 11 and above utilize the Holo theme otherwise the minimum in build.grade will be higher than the current minimum, changing the amount of devices which support the app.

Answer (score 0):

The dialog you are pointing was **HoloTheme** and the above white one was **AppCompatMaterial** theme. So if you want to use the Blue and Black, Then revert to Holo Theme

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context,android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use support v7 lib and make sure that you have import `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;` not `import android.app.AlertDialog;`

Comment: Devices using Honeycomb are version 9. The new minimum won't even be 10 it will be 11 using this method.

Comment: support.v7 lib support API 8 and more so you can use